# GPUImageMovieWriter frame presentationTime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, gpuimage

I have a `GPUImageColorDodgeBlend` filter with two inputs connected:

1. A `GPUImageVideoCamera` which is getting frames from the iPhone video camera.
2. A `GPUImageMovie` which is an (MP4) video file that I want to have laid over the live camera feed.

The `GPUImageColorDodgeBlend` is then connected to two outputs:

1. A `GPUImageImageView` to provide a live preview of the blend in action.
2. A `GPUImageMovieWriter` to write the movie to storage once a record button is pressed.

Now, before the video starts recording, everything works OK 100% of the time. The `GPUImageVideo` is blended over the live camera video fine, and no issues or warnings are reported.

However, when the `GPUImageMovieWriter` starts recording, things start to go wrong randomly. About 80-90% of the time, the `GPUImageMovieWriter` works perfectly, there are no errors or warnings and the output video is written correctly.

However, about 10-20% of the time (and from what I can see, this is fairly random), things seem to go wrong during the recording process (although the on-screen preview continues to work fine).

Specifically, I start getting hundreds & hundreds of `Program appending pixel buffer at time:` errors.

This error originates from the `- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex` method in `GPUImageWriter`.

This issue is triggered by problems with the `frameTime` values that are reported to this method.

From what I can see, the problem is caused by the writer sometimes receiving frames numbered by the video camera (which tend to have extremely high time values like **64616612394291** with a timescale of **1000000000**). But, then sometimes the writer gets frames numbered by the `GPUImageMovie` which are numbered much lower (like **200200** with a timescale of **30000**).

It seems that `GPUImageWriter` is happy as long as the frame values are increasing, but once the frame value decreases, it stops writing and just emits `Program appending pixel buffer at time:` errors.

**I seem to be doing something fairly common, and this hasn't been reported anywhere as a bug, so my questions are (answers to any or all of these are appreciated -- they don't all need to necessarily be answered sequentially as separate questions):**

- Where do the `frameTime` values come from -- why does it seem so arbitrary whether the `frameTime` is numbered according to the `GPUImageVideoCamera` source or the `GPUImageMovie` source? Why does it alternative between each -- shouldn't the frame numbering scheme be uniform across all frames?
- Am I correct in thinking that this issue is caused by non-increasing `frameTime`s?
- ...if so, why does `GPUImageView` accept and display the `frameTime`s just fine on the screen 100% of the time, yet `GPUImageMovieWriter` requires them to be ordered?
- ...and if so, how can I ensure that the `frameTime`s that come in are valid? I tried adding `if (frameTime.value < previousFrameTime.value) return;` to skip any lesser-numbered frames which works -- most of the time. Unfortunately, when I set `playsAtActualSpeed` on the `GPUImageMovie` this tends to become far less effective as *all* the frames end up getting skipped after a certain point.

...**or** perhaps this is a bug, in which case I'll need to report it on GitHub -- but I'd be interested to know if there's something I've overlooked here in how the `frameTime`s work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a potential solution to this issue, which I've implemented as a hack for now, but could conceivably be extended to a proper solution.

I've traced the source of the timing back to `GPUImageTwoInputFilter` which essentially multiplexes the two input sources into a single output of frames.

In the method `- (void)newFrameReadyAtTime:(CMTime)frameTime atIndex:(NSInteger)textureIndex`, the filter waits until it has collected a frame from the first source (`textureInput == 0`) and the second, and then forwards on these frames to its targets.

The problem (the way I see it) is that the method simply uses the `frameTime` of whichever frame comes in second (excluding the cases of still images for which `CMTIME_IS_INDEFINTE(frameTime) == YES` which I'm not considering for now because I don't work with still images) which may not always be the same frame (for whatever reason).

The relevant code which checks for both frames and sends them on for processing is as follows:

```
  if ((hasReceivedFirstFrame && hasReceivedSecondFrame) || updatedMovieFrameOppositeStillImage)
    {
        [super newFrameReadyAtTime:frameTime atIndex:0]; // this line has the problem
        hasReceivedFirstFrame = NO;
        hasReceivedSecondFrame = NO;
    }
```

What I've done is adjusted the above code to `[super newFrameReadyAtTime:firstFrameTime atIndex:0]` so that it **always** uses the `frameTime` from the *first* input and totally ignores the `frameTime` from the second input. So far, it's all working fine like this. (Would still be interested for someone to let me know why this is written this way, given that `GPUImageMovieWriter` seems to insist on increasing `frameTime`s, which the method as-is doesn't guarantee.)

Caveat: This will almost certainly break entirely if you work only with still images, in which case you will have `CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE(frameTime) == YES` for your first input's`frameTime`.

Comment: Yeah, the timing code in the whole framework needs some love. There's no synchronization between multiple video sources, and I didn't account for the case where two video sources are blended together, so it's no real surprise that there are problems here. I haven't spent much time on the movie input and recording side, so if you have some more improvements in this area, I'd be glad to take pull requests to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for your input Brad, I just need to incorporate some considerations the `updatedMovieFrameOppositeStillImage` case and I'll submit a pull request for a fix. Hopefully there are no undesirable side effects of taking the `frameTime`s from one input exclusively... (I've had no problems so far, but then again I am using GPUImage in a fairly specific use case)

Comment: I have a similar setup here, and it was somehow working fine using the version build with cocoa-pods. But I needed some of the new stuff and bug fixes, so I compiled from gpuimage master, and now it isn't working anymore, because it's getting ultra slow. So basically now I can't use GPUImageMovie together with GPUImageVideoCamera, any ideas?